# Show a page for a specific time using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, splash-screen, ionic-framework

I am using AngularJS and Ionic framework. I want to create a splash screen but not use `cloak`. After showing the splash screen for 10 seconds, my app should go to another page. This second page is designing with Ionic i.e. I use `ion-nav-view`, `ion-side-menus`, etc.

I don't know how to write this. I searched but couldn't find anything! Please tell me how I can write this or send to me a tutorial.

Comment: Use `$timeout` for 10 seconds and then navigate to other location as you wish using `$location.url()` or `$location.url()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you write a part of code that i can understand well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inject the `$location`in your controller or what ever

```
$timeout(function() {
       //will be directed to / after 3 seconds.
       $location.path('/');
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: This is true answer but i should set $location and $timeout to my controller. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I write this but after 3 seconds not change my page. I want to simulate a splash screen!

js:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('welcome', {
  url: '/welcome',
  //If in a folder, template/welcome.html    
  templateUrl: 'welcome.html',
  controller: 'WelcomeController'
})
 .state('splash', {
    url: '/splash',
    //If in a folder, template/login.html
    templateUrl: 'splash.html',
    controller: 'LoginController '
})


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");
})
 .controller('splashControlller', function ($scope) {
    $timeout(function () {
    //will be directed to / after 3 seconds.
    $location.path('/welcome');
}, 3000);
})
```

html:

```
  <body>
    <div>

      <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
      <script id="welcome.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view>
          <br /><br />
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </ion-view>
      </script>

      <script id="splash.html" type="text/ng-template">
          <ion-view ng-controller="splashController">
          <div class="kit-splash" >
                    <img class="jouyaSplashImg" alt="" src="Content/images/jouyaSplashImg.png"/>
                    <span class="splashVersion"></span>
                 </div>
        </ion-view>
          </script>
          </body>
```

Comment: `controller: 'LoginController '` should be `controller: 'splashControlller'`